# Python dict unpacking operator not unpacking string in constructor

Tags: python, class, dictionary, socket.io, iterable-unpacking

I am creating a small app using socketio in python on server side and JS on client side.
For one of my events, the client emits a character object that was created by the user in the browser to be persisted by the server.

On the server side, some validations are necessary before persistence, and so **i've created the Character class in order to keep all character validations and such, in one area.**

**Character has a constructor like so:**

```
class Character():
  def __init__(self, stats=None, strength=0, stamina=0, armor=0, agility=0, charisma=0, health=0, lowAttack=0, highAttack=0, attack=0, ability_points=16, characterName=""):
    if stats is None:
        stats = ['strength', 'stamina', 'armor', 'agility', 'charisma']
    self.stats = stats
    self.strength = strength
    self.stamina = stamina
    self.armor = armor
    self.agility = agility
    self.charisma = charisma
    self.health = health
    self.lowAttack = lowAttack
    self.highAttack = highAttack
    self.attack = attack
    self.ability_points = ability_points
    self.characterName = ""
```

Here is what the data looks like when it is first received by the sever as a dict:

```
{'stats': ['strength', 'stamina', 'armor', 'agility', 'charisma'], 'strength': 1, 'stamina': 0, 'armor': 0, 'agility': 0, 'charisma': 0, 'health': 0, 'lowAttack': 0, 'highAttack': 0, 'attack': 0, 'ability_points': 15, 'characterName': 'Buck County'}
```

it may be hard to notice in this example, but this dicts values are different than the default values in the constructor for the Character class, for example:

```
'strength': 1
'characterName': 'Buck County'
'ability_points': 15
```

**Most importantly noted in the above is the** `'characterName': 'Buck County'`

Ideally, what I would like to do next is turn this into an instance of a class in order to perform all the validations I've created and then just use `instance.__dict__` to persist it.

Right now, this is what i'm doing based on what i've read about unpacking:

```
newCharacter = Character(**character)
print(newCharacter.__dict__)
```

Here is what is printed from the above:

```
{'stats': ['strength', 'stamina', 'armor', 'agility', 'charisma'], 'strength': 1, 'stamina': 0, 'armor': 0, 'agility': 0, 'charisma': 0, 'health': 0, 'lowAttack': 0, 'highAttack': 0, 'attack': 0, 'ability_points': 15, 'characterName': ''}
```

So, below i'm going to put the print out of the **dict that is sent to the server from the client** vs the **dict that belongs to the class once dict has been unpacked into**.

```
{'stats': ['strength', 'stamina', 'armor', 'agility', 'charisma'], 'strength': 1, 'stamina': 0, 'armor': 0, 'agility': 0, 'charisma': 0, 'health': 0, 'lowAttack': 0, 'highAttack': 0, 'attack': 0, 'ability_points': 15, 'characterName': 'Buck County'}

{'stats': ['strength', 'stamina', 'armor', 'agility', 'charisma'], 'strength': 1, 'stamina': 0, 'armor': 0, 'agility': 0, 'charisma': 0, 'health': 0, 'lowAttack': 0, 'highAttack': 0, 'attack': 0, 'ability_points': 15, 'characterName': ''}
```

You can see in the comparison very clearly that the only value not being properly unpacked is the name. Instead, it is resulting to the default value ""

I am new with Python and come from a Java / JS background. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you mean: `self.characterName = characterName`?

Comment: Wow, yes I definitely did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the issue, but it looks like in your `__init__`, you define `self.characterName = ""`, not `self.characterName = characterName`